# reverse page numbers with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Is there any simple way to reverse page numeration with `will_paginate`?

I want for the top page (last time-wise) to be #1, and the last (earliest) to be #N.

The reason for that is page contents shouldn't change with time, which is good for SEO.

Comment: Actually, fresh page content on pages is good for SEO.  Google likes fresh content changes.  In general, you want Google to crawl your paginated listings, but you don't want Google to index paginated listings (because they do change).  You want Google to index the pages that the paginated listings point to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Order your query by an ascending date instead of a descending date**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at ASC"
end
```

Comment: Shit, it's really that simple. All I have to do is customize the paginator template so it reverses the visible order of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. If the oldest content is #N, then when there's new content, the oldest content will be pushed to #N+1 and the page contents would change. That sounds like it's the opposite of what you're looking for?

You can pass `:order => "column ASC"` or `:order => "column DESC"` to paginate to determine what ends up on page #1.